# referring to different textboxes on each iteration

Tags: vba

I'm making a Visual Basic program. I have a page where I want to be able to scale anywhere from 1 set of two textboxes and a label all the way up to 30. I'd really like to keep the display as simple as possible, So I'm trying to make buttons like add batch and remove batch that lets me adjust the boxes shown from 1 to 30.

I know that I can use a case statement or a if statement or even making a function that does one of those for me so I don't clutter up the main code, but that just seems so klunky. Any suggestions on a way that I can refer to one set at one time and another set at one time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a class that and passed references ByRef to the class. Created methods of Show*( and Hide() that show and hide all objects that were passed to the class (just changing the Visible property)

Created one object of my new class for each batch set. Made an array with those objects in it, now I can call BatchGroups(3).Show() and iterate through my batches.

Still a bit of setup in my FormLoad event, but BatchGroup(txtBat1,txtBatQty1,lblBat1) and filling an array with those objects allows me to iterate through my batches whether I am adding, removing, adding 5 at a time, removing all but one... take your pick.

Could probably build an array with groupboxes as easily to refer to the whole group at once, but groupboxes would have looked somewhat tacky in this situation, I preferred to create my own object oriented groups.